# C# CodeProvider: Add reference to XNA?

Tags: c#, scripting, xna

I'm creating a scripting engine for my game, and I need C# scripts to have the Microsoft.XNA.Framework assembly referenced so that I can inherit from my own classes.

Currently, I error when I add a reference to Microsoft.XNA.Framework.dll. This is my reference adding code (I've left out the reference to my own EXE, but it is there.):

```
parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll");
parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.dll");
parms.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
```

And here is  my code to be compiled:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.XNA.Framework;
using Microsoft.XNA.Framework.Graphics;
namespace _2342 {
namespace Blocks {
    class MyClass : Block
    {
        public MyClass() {
        _name = "TestBlock";
        }
    }
}}
```

I get two errors from the CodeProvider saying that neither of the XNA DLLs can be found.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled the assembly name 'Microsoft.XNA.Framework'. It should be 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework'

Answer (score 0):

This might be related or have relevance. When i did that for my scripting engine it choked since XNA is in the GAC.
Therefore i had to do something like this

```cs
ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Windows\x86\Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll");
```

with "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XNA" being the install path of my XNA dlls.

Comment: Yes, I have since modified my code to go directly to the installed files using the registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\XNA\Game Studio\v4.0\ From there you can get the path of the install, and in that path there is a subfolder with all of the DLLs in.